# Why 'app:processDebugManifest' error always happens?

Tags: android

I know, there are thousands of questions like this,but I tried all solutions and they didn't work for me. So,what is the problem? The problem is error below: 
[image]

One of the solutions is to use same version specification. I use 26.0.0 version and all libraries too. But error happens anyway. Also, `appcompat` error doesn't disappear. It shows that `all support libraries must use same version` and there is a red underline. Below is my app level build.gradle file:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apps.root.exampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 24
        versionName "2.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // Optional: Specify the language(s) your app supports.
        resConfigs "ru", "kz", "en"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0.6.jar')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.krossovochkin.bottomsheetmenu:bottomsheetmenu:1.1'
    compile 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
/*
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
*/
```

After this trial, I went to manifest file. I tried to add `tools:replace="android:value"` to application tag. But it didn't help.I clicked to `Merged Manifest` , and it shows following:

[image]

Below is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.zerotoonelabs.root.qamqor">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:name=".PrefsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        tools:replace="android:value">
        <meta-data

            android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ApplicationName"
            android:value="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data

            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/FACEBOOK_APP_ID" />
        <meta-data

            android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN" />
        <meta-data

            android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data

            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_kazakhstan" />

        <meta-data

            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />


        <meta-data

            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".login.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LetterDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.RulesActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".login.EditProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".login.SignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".login.SignUpActivity2" />

        <activity android:name=".ate.UserLocation" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.DomainDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ChangePasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SuggestionActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".login.RestorePasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ShowPdfActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SeeLetterDetaily" />
        <activity android:name=".GuestActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.LoginViaFacebookActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.PhoneAuthActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".ChooseItemActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".GuestingActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".VideoPlayerActivity"></activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

If  I remove `tools:replace` in manifest , then error will be following:

[image]
It also adviced me to add `replace` into `meta-data` tags that I have, but it didn't help too. So,the question is how to solve this problem?

Comment: please post your Manifest file

Comment: @ItzikSamar Done! Need your help

Comment: Why do u need tools:replace="android:value"???

Comment: @ItzikSamar Android Studio suggests me to do so. If  I remove it , the error will be something like: attribute meta-data is also present at Android Manifest. Suggestion is to add replace .

Comment: Start with this.. compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1' use the last version (there is 26.0.0 withput the alpha) plus the error indicate that your got 2 lib with 26 but with different sub version : compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1' compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.+' .. also check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification

Comment: @itzikSamara What I did after reading your advice: 1)changed appcompat to 26.0.0 . Underline error still appears. 2)Changed support design to 26.0.0 3)Synced the project, but didn't help. Error is: Suggestion:add tools:replace

Comment: have you changed to implementation instead of compile?

Comment: @itzikSamara No,I don't use implementation. I don't think that the problem is there.